# Not able to install any new package by PIP | Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I want to install a new package GraphLab in my Anaconda environment but its not coming when I searched there  so not able to install it from Anaconda, please suggest how to install from Anaconda itself 
[image]

Then I want to install it from PIP but its is also showing error, then I tried to install any popular package to check if PIP is working as expected then again also showing below mentioned error 
[image]

Python Version : 3.6.4
PIP Version : 10.0.1

Error

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000463C278>, 'Connection to files.pyt
onhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/5e/1f/6c2204b9ae14ed
ab615c5e2ee4956c65ed533e0a9986c23eabd801ae849/selenium-3.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.
hl
```

Can someone please help me to find my next steps.

Comment: these queries work for me  first : pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org selenium; second :
conda config --set ssl_verify false

Answer (score 0):

1. Graphlab Create requires an [academic license](https://turi.com/download/academic.html) to use.
2. GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7 and Anaconda2 v4.0.0 (64-bit). IPython Notebook is recommended.
3. [Install GraphLab Create with Command Line](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html)